# 'RNSplashScreen.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, splash-screen, react-native-splash-screen

I recently purchased a new MacBook M2 Pro and cloned my React Native app onto it. However, I'm encountering an error stating that the 'RNSplashScreen.h' file cannot be found, even though I have not included the 'react-native-splash-screen' package in my project. Despite trying various solutions from online sources, the issue persists only on my system, while other developers using the same system do not face this problem. What could I be overlooking?[image]

Comment: Did you do pod install ?

Comment: Yes, deleted cache data of xcode also -> clean the build -> Restarted the system but still the same error. Please help